# ¿Qué picamos cuando alguien se "pica"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

Con frecuencia decimos en España:

> Ayer le dije a Juan que es un calzonazos y se picó.

Es decir, con *picar* indicamos que alguien se enfada.

El DRAE lo recoge así:

> [**picar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SsuIXMH)
>
> De pico<sup>1</sup>.
>
> 1. tr. Pinchar una superficie con un instrumento punzante. U. t. c. prnl.
>
> (...)
>
> 20. tr. Enojar y provocar a alguien con palabras o acciones.
>
> (...)
>
> 55. prnl. coloq. Ofenderse, enfadarse o enojarse, a causa de alguna
>       palabra o acción ofensiva o indecorosa.

Pero me interesa el origen de la expresión: ¿qué se supone que estamos picando cuando alguien se pica? ¿picamos su amor propio, su orgullo? ¿acaso estamos *pinchando* en su estado de ánimo?

Comment: Creo que picarse en relación enfadarse tiene mas que ver con la sensación de picor que se rasca que con picar una piedra.

Comment: En este sentido, el verbo es intransitivo, por lo que no picamos nada. Quizá esta expresión tenga que ver con el picante, por eso de que _quien se pica, ajos come_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Viene del sustantivo "pique":

> **[pique](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T7pDG6p%7CT7s8Aoc%7CT7s8uyl)**
>
> De picar.
>
> 1. m. Resentimiento, desazón o disgusto ocasionado de una disputa u otra cosa semejante.

Yo no lo había escuchado nunca. Estos ejemplos los obtuve de Google:

> Sevilla y Villarreal tienen un pique deportivo por su competitividad.
>
> Tienen un pique que comenzó por un problema familiar.

También existe con el mismo significado en [inglés](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/pique) ([etimología en dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pique)).

La variante pronominal, mucho más frecuente, se forma como siempre:

> Un disgusto - *disgustarse* - *te disgustaste*
>
> Un corte - *cortarse* - *te cortaste*
>
> Un pique - *picarse* - *te picaste*

Como se menciona en la definición, deriva de **picar** que, según el Breve Diccionario Etimológico de Joan Corominas, es una palabra de origen onomatopéyico, común a todas las lenguas romances. Originalmente significó "golpear con algo puntiagudo" (pic-pic-pic) y derivó hacia muchos sentidos diferentes.

Al "picarte" (que gramaticalmente es lo mismo que "disgustar**te**") sientes como que te pincharan con una aguja (que es lo que hacen los *picadores* de toros). Es esencialmente lo mismo que te ocurre con la *picazón* y la comida *picante*.

Comment: La expresión inglesa viene del francés [*piquer*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/piquer/61107), que aún conserva el significado de ofender o irritar, de alrededor de 1530 (Etymonline). También hay ejemplos en español de *pique* en el sentido de ofensa por estas fechas, como en la expresión *dar pique*: "porque en otra ida y venida, / cierto fullero angelote / a la honra le dio pique" (Góngora, 1580-1627).

Comment: Interesantísima respuesta (¡como siempre!), gracias Rodrigo. Me has convencido, voy a comprarme el Breve Diccionario Etimológico de Coromines. Y después, el Dardo en la palabra de Carreter.

Comment: Qué curioso que no la hayas escuchado nunca. La verdad es que no sé en el resto de España, pero en Andalucía _tener un pique_ es una expresión muy conocida.

Comment: Siempre tuve la imagen de que es como decir que las palabras usadas son como agujas con filo, y de ser que el insulto no se da, se recibe, es uno el que se pica, no es picado. Parece ser que no es así.