# Palabra más polivalente del español

Tags: uso-de-palabras, rae, curiosidades

Tras leer la pregunta de fedorqui sobre [picarse](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17092/qu%C3%A9-picamos-cuando-alguien-se-pica), me sorprendió ver que el verbo picar tiene [57 acepciones](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SsuIXMH) aceptadas. Así que me pregunto: ¿cuál es la palabra más polivalente (con más acepciones) del español según la RAE? Siempre, claro, con el permiso de Pérez-Reverte y su *[cojones](http://arturoperez-reverte.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/cuestion-de-cojones.html)*.

Comment: Ese texto se atribuía hace años a Cela. En realidad, aunque sí es cierto que Cela escribió un ensayo sobre la palabra *cojones*, el texto es apócrifo.

Comment: @Gorpik tienes razón, es apócrifo, pero se ve que el señor Pérez-Reverte obtuvo una copia del texto y lo mencionó en uno de sus artículos. He cambiado el enlace para reflejar el artículo completo del escritor comentando dicho texto.

Comment: Polivalente y polisémica no son lo mismo. Polivalente es que sirve para muchas cosas; polisémica, que tiene muchos significados.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pues parece que la ganadora es...

- [**Pasar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S33P1kX), con 64 acepciones (y 9 locuciones)

Además, otras que tienen bastantes son:

- [picar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SsuIXMH), con 57 (y 3 locuciones)
- [dar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=dar), con 53 (y 52 locuciones).
- [bajo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4oyrC6G), con 51 (y 6 locuciones)
- [tirar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zr3ZJPx), con 39 (y 8 locuciones)
- [ir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy), con 38 (y 58 locuciones)

En [Búsqueda: La palabra con más acepciones en la RAE, y otras que también tengan muchas](http://zonaforo.meristation.com/topic/1320967/) estuvieron debatiéndolo hace unos cuantos años.

Comment: He sido incapaz de encontrar un término con más acepciones, así que tuya es la respuesta correcta. :-)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡gracias! He convertido la respuesta en community wiki para intentar centralizar algo más la información, pues estoy seguro que en el futuro iremos encontrando nuevas _curiosidades_.

Answer (score 7):

Consultada a la RAE me dicen que los artículos más extensos, contando acepciones simples y formas complejas, son los de **[mano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo%7COFAJXYy)** (372 acepciones en total) y **[pie](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SwyZKJX)** (217 acepciones en total), por ese orden.

No responde a la pregunta exacta, pero no por ello dejan de ser términos extremadamente polivalentes.

Answer (score 6):

Entre los sustantivos me llama la atención [**punto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UgMIq14), con 43 acepciones y 110 locuciones.

Comment: Me quito el sombrero. ¡Contaste las 110!

Answer (score 4):

Desconozco si hay alguna con más, pero [**hacer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jwhmcap) gana a **picar** justo por uno, 58 acepciones.

Por otro lado, si bien solo tiene [7 entradas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MVjNCIs), **joder** es la palabra a la que coloquialmente más significados se le dan (en mi opinión).

Answer (score 1):

Pues resulta que [a raíz de otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22586/13628), me encuentro con que [**dar**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=dar) tiene ¡53 acepciones y 52 locuciones! Algunas de las cuales tienen de por sí varias acepciones también, ejemplo:

> **dar abajo**
>   1. loc. verb. Precipitarse, dejarse caer.
>   2. loc. verb. coloq. *Cuba*. Excluir o despedir a alguien de algo.
>   3. loc. verb. coloq. *Cuba*. Retirar de su uso un objeto.
>   4. loc. verb. coloq. *Cuba*. Rechazar una propuesta.

Lo incluyo en el *ranking* de la respuesta CW.