# ¿Cuál es la palabra del español que puede desempeñar más funciones diferentes?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, dle, curiosidades

Consultando en el diccionario la palabra **[bien](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5TkGdE0)**, me encuentro con que puede ser:

1. Sustantivo: *Hacer el bien. Los bienes familiares.*
2. Adverbio: *Juan conduce bien. Pedro no se encuentra bien.*
3. Adjetivo: *Una familia bien. Gente bien.*
4. Conjunción: *Lo haremos bien hoy, bien mañana.*

Así que pregunta de curiosidad: **¿cuál es la palabra del español que puede desempeñar más funciones diferentes?** Siempre según el DRAE, claro.

En una pregunta similar ([Palabra más polivalente del español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17100/12637)) se preguntaba por la palabra con más acepciones. Aquí se pregunta por la que tiene más funciones posibles (es decir, que pueda actual como sustantivo, como adverbio, etc.). En el ejemplo: "bien" tiene cuatro posibles funciones. ¿Hay alguna palabra que por sí sola pueda desempeñar más funciones?

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/palabra-m%C3%A1s-polivalente-del-espa%C3%B1ol/17102#17102 Tu participaste en esas respuestas. ¿Qué diferenciaría esta pregunta de aquella otra?

Comment: @DGaleano he editado la pregunta para que quede claro que no es la misma cuestión que la que mencionas. :)

Comment: Me atrevería a pensar que 4 es el límite. P. ej **bajo** es sustantivo, adverbio, adjetivo, preposición. Sería difícil que una preposición también sea conjunción para que la palabra cumpla 5 funciones.

Comment: :-)  I got you an answer but in English. It as word that can be. Intransitive verb, transitive verb, adjective, adverb, noun,  prefix, suffix and many others. Curious? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZkb4TPI-Lo

Comment: Pues me da la sensación que con _bien_ ya contestaste la pregunta, no se me ocurre ninguna palabra que sea más "transversal" que esta :)

Comment: ¿cuentan los homófonos (más/mas)?, ¿y las conjugaciones verbales (p.ej. como)?

Comment: @Rafael no cuentan los homófonos (por ejemplo, _hasta_ y _asta_), se deben escribir igual. Pero sí valdrían los tiempos verbales: efectivamente, _como_ se puede interpretar como verbo.

Comment: @DGaleano según el último comentario, en realidad _bajo_ tendría cinco usos, ya que también es tiempo verbal.

Comment: como/cómo: ¿son palabras disintas? Puede ser adverbio (de 5 tipos distintos), conjunción, preposición, verbo, sustantivo e interjección.

Comment: @Rafael para eso nos guiamos por el hecho de que la RAE los considera palabras distintas al estar en entradas distintas del diccionario, así que no valdría. Sí valdría _como_ como verbo, ya que al buscar esa palabra te ofrece el infinitivo _comer_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **menos**

1. Adverbio: Estaba **menos** lejos de lo que creíamos.
2. Adjetivo: Compró **menos** tornillos que tuercas.
3. Pronombre: Cada día se conforma con **menos**.
4. Sustantivo: El signo **menos**. (-)
5. Conjunción: Todo **menos** eso.

**¡5 USOS!**

Va ganando.

Ejemplos tomados de: http://dle.rae.es/?id=OuzZNmN

y aunque en uno de mis primeros comentarios pensé que solo tenia 4 usos, Carlos me hace caer en cuenta que son 5 así:

### bajo

1. Adjetivo: El precio es **bajo**.
2. Sustantivo: El **bajo**. (instrumento musical).
3. Adverbio: Pon la radio más **bajo**.
4. Preposición: **Bajo** pena de muerte.
5. Verbo: Yo **bajo** las escaleras.

Comment: ¡Sabía yo que había alguna palabra con más funciones! Igualmente, "[más](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWErHxJ)" también tiene los mismos cinco usos.

Comment: Menos lejos suena muy forzado. ¿Que tal "El lugar estaba menos concurrido de lo que parecía"? Menos lejos sería reemplazo por "más cerca" casi sin pensarlo (al menos en España)

Comment: Te adjudico la respuesta correcta mientras no aparezca una de seis. :-)

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado otras palabras de 5 usos:

### [tanto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z60aNMi)

1. Adjetivo. *Hace **tanto** calor que no se puede dormir.*
2. Pronombre. *Tenía mucho calor, **tanto** que no aguantaba.*
3. Sustantivo. *Mi equipo ganó por un **tanto** a cero.*
4. Adverbio. *Llueve **tanto** como ayer.*
5. Conjunción. ***Tanto*** ella como su madre llegaron tarde.

### [cuanto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BSKD07C%7CBSKWl78)

1. Sustantivo ("cantidad indivisible de energía, proporcional a la frecuencia del campo al que se asocia"). ***Cuanto*** de energía
2. Adjetivo. ***Cuanto*** más tiempo dedico al asunto, menos lo entiendo.
3. Pronombre. *Siempre consigue **cuanto** quiere.*
4. Adverbio. *Llora **cuanto** quieras.*
5. Conjunción. *Era famosa tanto por sus éxitos **cuanto** por sus fracasos.*

Una lástima que ninguna de las dos palabras sea también una forma verbal. ¡A ver si alguien encuentra una de seis!