# ¿Cómo definir el tipo gramatical de un verbo con significados similares?

Tags: gramática, rae, dle, asale

Viendo [una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/palabra-m%C3%A1s-polivalente-del-espa%C3%B1ol) acerca de las palabras con más significados, se me ocurrió incluir el uso del ASALE, que aumentaría acepciones y locuciones de varias palabras, pero me llamó la atención en particular que el verbo tirar aparece como verbo pronominal en el DLE en su acepción 38 (Poseer sexualmente a alguien) y como intransitivo en el diccionario de la ASALE en su acepción I (Mantener relaciones sexuales con alguien). Siendo significados similares, ¿Qué causa el cambio gramatical en el verbo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sé si he comprendido la pregunta adecuadamente, pero en el caso de ese verbo, este es tanto intransitivo como pronominal (si uno se refiere en el último caso el valor del “se”). Supongo que la revisión de las acepciones habrá movido las posiciones de las mismas, pero hasta donde entiendo, el uso indicado es el mismo.

**Edit**

Por si no ha quedado suficientemente claro: @VeAqui el verbo es el mismo, no son verbos distintos. Con esa acepción es intransitivo y pronominal; intransitivo porque no toma objeto directo, pronominal porque emplea un pronombre que no afecta directamente a su significado:

> **Marca de verbo pronominal/pseudorreflexivo**
>
> 1. María se asustó mucho.
> 2. Juan se rompió una pierna.
> 3. Se puso todo nervioso.
> 4. No se arrepiente de nada.
> 5. Se quedó tan tranquilo.
> 6. Se fue de clase sin decir nada.
> 7. Se levantó y se marchó.

Recurso de una página oficial de la Xunta de Galicia, gobierno de una región de España con competencias académicas.
http://www.edu.xunta.gal/centros/iesfranciscodavinarey/system/files/USOS+DE+SE.pdf

Se la tiró puede significar:

**Le tiró una piedra a ella > se la tiró**

La: complemento indirecto (a ella)
Se: sustituye a le, para evitar cacofonía, es el complemento directo (la piedra)

**Mantuvo relaciones sexuales con ella > se la tiró**

Obviando el brutal cambio de registro de la frase, estas son equivalentes en términos estrictamente significativos. La es un complemento indirecto, y se es un complemento pronominal. No hay complemento directo, por lo que el verbo es intransitivo. En el primer caso, el verbo estaba actuando como transitivo, porque sí tenía objeto directo.

Si estás estudiando español como extranjero, no te recomiendo que ahondes demasiado en los valores de 'se' antes de conseguir una buena base de la lengua en general. Puede darte muchos dolores de cabeza en esta particularidad la gramática española, pues es bastante flexible.

Si el español es tu lengua nativa, te recomiendo que consultes algún manual de gramática o de sintaxis que explique con más detalle estos aspectos, pues seguro que quedarán mejor ejemplificados y definidos que por mí.

Un abrazo.

Comment: @JuanRocamonte, preferiría que complementaras con ejemplos de los verbos en su uso correspondiente, para que la respuesta quede mejor. Gracias

Comment: @VeAqui he editado la respuesta con una explicación más extensa.