# What is the meaning of "No se me habrá pasado usted con los postres. ¿Verdad?"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

What does this actually mean?

> No se me habrá pasado usted con los postres. ¿Verdad?

I would translate it something like this:

> You will not have passed me with the desserts, have you?

Pero estoy seguro de que no es correcto.

Comment: The key here is the use of the verb [pasar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S33P1kX) used in a pronominal way. It can have multiple meanings, but in here it means to eat way too much.

Comment: However, it may be good if you dig a bit on it, so we can then provide an extense answer on the matter. Do you feel comfortable browsing through the link I provided with the meanings of the word?

Comment: After lunch, I'll open the link and dig a bit deeper for sure!

Comment: @fedorqui remember that _pasar_ is the word with [the most number of different meanings in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17102/12637)... :-)

Comment: I lloked at the page and woow it will take more than a day to go through and actually understand all the meanings of pasar. Indeed Charlie must be right about the word having the most number of different meanings in spanish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this is a tricky one for non-natives. For the Spanish it's very natural, but it has two implicit things:

1. Pasarse = to cross (to cross the line). It comes from "pasarse de la raya" (to cross the line), or a similar one. "Pasarse" means to exceed.
2. The usage of an ethical dative. That "me" in your sentence is completely dispensable; you can remove it and the sentence means the same. Its function is about nuances.

That "me" adds "closeness" and trust. Despite using "usted", the one who adds this "me" certainly wants to "promote links" or something like that. It makes a warmer atmosphere. Usted can be used for elegant and respectful conversations with unknown people. This "me" turns it into a more friendly conversation. If you want more info about this, you can ask.

3. And finally, the greatest difficulty: the future tense with meaning of premise.

Sometimes, the future tense is used for "conjecture or probability about a past finished event".

For example

> Ya habrá llegado = Ya debe de haber llegado = It must have already
>   arrived = It has probably already arrived.

So, in your sentence, it actually means `No te has pasado con el postre, ¿verdad?`

As you can see, this usage of the future tense in questions can be perfectly replaced by a normal present tense (present perfect).

So, in sum, your sentence would mean

> You haven't crossed (the line) with the desserts, right?

Comment: Según el contexto, podría tener otros significados. Puede ser el camarero preguntando al cliente algo así como: "¿No ha pedido Vd. demasiados postres?". O si es el cliente  que se dirige al camarero que lleva el carrito con los postres pero no se acerca a la mesa del cliene, algo parecido a lo que supone el OP?

Comment: Una respuesta excellente FGSUZ y DGaleano. Gracias! Ahora lo entiendo y voy a usar la frase cuando pueda para impresionar el professor un poco.:)

Comment: I kind of understand the meaning of me there as well. I would interpret it like in this following example: "don't you get sick FOR ME sir" "No se me enferme usted Senor!"