# La palabra con el número máximo de sentidos

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones, diccionarios

Todos hemos visto las palabras que tienen varios sentidos. Tengo entendido que en el inglés el término ambiguo ["set"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set#English) será el campeón.

Según la DRAE y considerando todas las partes de la oración, ¿cuál es la palabra más ampliamente definida?

Comment: Psst, check [Palabra más polivalente del español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17100/5481). Was this what you were trying to ask?

Comment: Exactamente. Gracias!

Comment: @Diego - What does "psst" mean in this context?  What flavor are you intending to get across?  Do you mean something like "Oye"?  It feels a tiny, tiny bit strong to my ear.

Comment: Never fear, I'm not offended. Perhaps it was this definition: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/psst#Interjection